# How to secure Azure Serverless Microservice Architecture?

Tags: azure

**I am trying to build Serverless Microservice Architecture**

**Azure services used by me are:**

- Azure CDN
- Azure Active Directory
- Azure Logic Apps
- Azure Functions
- Azure Event Grid
- Azure SignalR Service

**Which below tools do I need mange and secure my API in Azure Serverless Microservice Architecture?**

- Azure Traffic Manager
- Azure Application Gateway
- Azure API Management
- Azure Function Proxy

**Links Referred by me are :**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/serverless/web-app

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serverless-architecture/serverless-design-examples

Please help

**Edit:**

I understand above tools and it purpose but what I can't understand is do I require them, if yes in what order, all I am developing is an Angular 2+ app, post a Command Event to Azure Functions/Logic Apps using REST api returning RequestId (and triggering chain of events) and subscribing to that RequestId to listen for Domain Event.

Answer (score 0):

This is very broad Architecture question.  All the services you mentioned have specific purpose. You can even secure your functions without using any of them by simply turning on authentication on functions.

I would suggest reading all of them in details can help you identify which service may suit your needs in this case. e.g. Traffic manager is used for cross region traffic distribution and may not be required in your case. Function proxies and Api management overlap in few cases and really depends on what you are trying to achieve.  To get better idea you may need to share your architecture diagram.